# Insert class instance in a List to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory, clr, directoryservices

What is the best way to insert a List of class instances in SQL 2008 R2 table?

I am using C# in a CLR Procedure to get and insert the data.

I am trying to insert information of computer objects from Active Directory into SQL server table.
With System.DirectoryServices, the objects are retrieved in a "SearchResultCollection". I modify each "searchresult" object to my custom class "ComputerObject".

Then I put them in a list `List<ComputerObject>`, 
how do I insert each "ComputerObject" as rows in a SQL table ? I don't want to use a single insert statement for each row.

If needed, I can also retrieve the `List<ComputerObject>` into another Data Structure, so that it will be easier to insert into a SQL table.

Also, whenever the CLR Proc runs, data is appended to the table.

Thank you.

Comment: What language? What SQL dialect?

Comment: C# 3.0 using a CLR Proc to get the data and insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008+ and I assume you are using a .NET language, you will probably be interested in using ADO.NET to interact with a database.  2008 allows for table valued parameters and I'd suggest you look at using those as an effective means of smashing a list into a table.  Detailed example of using [Table Valued Parameters and C#](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/06/t-sql-tuesday-007-summertime-in-sql.html) to load data into a database here.

Otherwise, edit your question into something useful.

Comment: C# 3.0 using a CLR Proc to get the data and insert it.

Comment: I think we're still looking for a better explanation of what you are attempting to accomplish. What is the data type of your list? What would a simplified schema look like. Is the C# application going to invoke the CLR proc to get data and then a different method writes it into the database? Are you looking to modify the proc to get and write data.  See how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask